# Is it possible to play vimeo video in iphone native application using UIWebView approach?

Tags: iphone, youtube-api, vimeo

[There is UIWebView approach to play YouTube video inside native IPhone Application](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html).
Does anybody tried to do the sane for vimeo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible when user has shared his video using "plus" account. Otherwise vimeo will render static image in Iphone.

Answer (score 1):

It's only possible if Vimeo supports HTML5 video, [which looks like it does.](http://vimeo.com/blog:268)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:

@"<html>"
@"<body>"
@"<meta name = \"viewport\"content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no\"/>"
@"<iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/8118831title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=008efe&amp\";autoplay=1&amp;loop=1 width=\"320\" height=\"480\" frameborder=\"0\">"
@"</iframe>"
@"<body style=\"background:#000;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\">"
@"</object></div></body></html>",@"http://www.vimeo.com/8118831"
];
```

Now just use `loadHTMLString` to play the video in your application.